# Freemarker Configuration in a spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, freemarker, spring-tool-suite

I am migrating a multi module maven project from SpringToolsSuite to IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition. I am using freemarker to generate xml files. When I launch the project from STS the template folder is well configured and the template is found and everything works.

But when I run the application from Intellij Idea the template folder is not found by the system.

Here is the error from the stacktrace:

freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "AnaCredit_Bbk_Riad.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: FileTemplateLoader(baseDir="C:\", canonicalBasePath="C:\").

My code to set the directory for template loading is this:

```
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/"));
```

These properties exists in application.yml:

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path: /
spring.freemarker.suffix: .ftl
```

What must be configured to get the same results in both STS and Idea?
Why does it work in SpringToolsSuite but not in Idea?

Comment: You are telling FreeMarker above to load templates from C:\. That can't be right. Unless you indeed have that template at `C:\AnaCredit_Bbk_Riad.ftl`, but that would be rather weird...

Comment: No. It works in STS

Comment: Well, I guess something overrides it there, or something adds a fallback location... `cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/"));` is still incorrect, and should be removed. (I have no idea why the IDE matters here, especially as the actual deployed application runs without any.) Maybe you have something like `application.properties` that Spring Boot won't find in one case, and that's where the template loader is overridden...